# Autocomplete term widget (tagging) - Insert as child

Tags: 7, ajax, taxonomy-terms

Is there a way to insert taxonomy terms as child of a parent term with the auto complete term widget?

I have found several modules such as "Content Taxonomy" or "Hierarchical Term Reference Autocomplete", but couldn't find this specific feature.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some research on this as we use the [Autocomplete Deluxe](https://drupal.org/project/autocomplete_deluxe) module for our client's sites. Unfortunately I see no preexisting solution and I think you will have to create your own.

This could be quite visually problematical. How do you display this in a auto complete field: Prefixed with all its parents? with a parent attribute type key?

I agree that this could be quite useful as this would eliminate the need to give a non-technical user admin access to taxonomy more and more. But I think this would be better achieved with a custom coded mix of Autocomplete Deluxe and [Hierarchical select](https://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select)